# php and htaccess to add vanity to a url with multiple levels

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an .htaccess file which I am using to hide php extensions and add vanity to a directory. For example the users profile page would display:

> mydomain.com/usersname  instead of  mydomain.com?user=username

This works fine as does the hiding .php extensions, this comes in handy for error pages or form registration pages. For example

> mydomain.com/errors/404.php would become mydomain.com/errors/404

So to pick up the users profile I use I simple $_GET on the page. Is it possible to have multiple levels of this within the .htaccess file

so instead of

```
#vanity on a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC]
```

to find the users profile would it be possible to do something like this to vwie users images.

> mydomain.com/username/images

```
#vanity on a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1&&page=$2 [NC]
```

The first method works fine to get my users profile but when I add anythings else to the url I get something like this:

> mydomain.com/username/images
>
> Array ( [user] =>username/images.php/images [page] => )

My full .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine ON
#Error Handling
ErrorDocument 403     http://localhost/mysite/error/403
ErrorDocument 404     http://localhost/mysite/error/404
ErrorDocument 500     http://localhost/mysite/error/500
# hide php extentions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

#vanity on a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1&&page=$2 [NC]
```

Comment: How can you add vanity to an inanimate virtual entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starkeen's answer takes care of the fact that your code is confusing accessing user profiles with accessing normal pages.

The problem with translating multiple levels into multiple GET variables has the following solution: extend the regular expression. For example, if you need two levels you can replace the last line with:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/.]*)\/([^\/.]*)\/?$ profile.php?user=$1&&image=$2 [NC,L]
```

This also allows for a trailing slash like test_user/test_image/. If the user can input a variable number of levels you will need to use several RewriteRules, starting with the one with the most levels and going down. Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/.]*)\/([^\/.]*)\/?$ profile.php?user=$1&&image=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

You can easily extend it to as many levels and variables as you like as long as the order is known.

Comment: that was a bit confusing at first but I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace  your both rule with :

```
#Remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

#vanity on a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I replaced my code with your answers, it works in exactly the same way as it did before. Is this a cleaner way of writing what I all ready had?

Comment: Your code created  a  loop error on my server. /foo/bar Was converted to /foo/bar.php and then it got rewritten to "/profile?user="